# logout is not woking properly

Tags: php, cookies

```
<?php
setcookie("id","",time()-1200,'/bss/bss/');
session_start();
session_destroy();
header("location:http://localhost/bss/bss/");
?>
```

This is my logout page when i click on this it will redirect me to the header location but when i click on back button on the top-left side , it will show me the whole info but i m logout . and if i refresh on this page again it will show me the normal page without my info 
cookies is destroyed but when i click on back button why its showing me the page wid my info . is there any way when the user click on the back button IT cant go back

Comment: are you using the cookie to identify if the user is logged ?

Answer (score 5):

`<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE, NO-STORE, must-revalidate">`
`<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">`
`<META HTTP-EQUIV="EXPIRES" CONTENT=0>`

its a solution that prevents caching we can't wipe the cache for what they already loaded.
You should look it too [prevent back button after logout page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10016615/prevent-back-button-after-logout-page)

Answer (score 1):

Just redirect if there's no login $_SESSION, for example:

```
//on your protected pages
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['logged']) {
    header("location:login.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to clear browser cache by using these lines in all pages

```
header("Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
```

Comment: if my logout page is redirecting to my index page den where should i write the header info , I am wokring on this for the first time so I have no idea about this

Answer (score 0):

try this mate

```
<?php
   setcookie("id","",time()-1200,'/');

   session_start();
   session_destroy();

   header("location:http://localhost/bss/bss/");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE, NO-STORE, must-revalidate">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="EXPIRES" CONTENT=0>
```

(If you are not using templates) Put this in your html pages

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if cookie is present in every page with only member access.Do the following if you havent:

1->check if cookie exists

2->if exists show info page

3->doesnt exist redirect to `http://localhost/bss/bss/`